# R: Import CSV with column names that contain spaces

Tags: r, csv

CSV file looks like this (modified for brevity). Several columns have spaces in their title and R can't seem to distinguish them.

```
Alias;Type;SerialNo;DateTime;Main status; [...]
E1;E-70;781733;01/04/2010 11:28;8; [...]
```

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
s_data <- read.csv2( file=f_name )
attach(s_data)

s_df = data.frame( 
                scada_id=ID,
                plant=PlantNo, 
                date=DateTime,
                main_code=Main status,
                seco_code=Additional Status,
                main_text=MainStatustext,
                seco_test=AddStatustext,
                duration=Duration)

detach(s_data)
```

I have also tried substituting

```
main_code=Main\ status
```

and

```
main_code="Main status"
```

Comment: @klonq :  why not try read.table function , i support space in the column name

Comment: @smack: not quite. `read.csv2` is just a wrapper for `read.table`, so it supports the same things.  In either case you can use `check.names=TRUE` to allow spaces in the column names (but it's generally not a good idea)

Comment: The data you have pasted from the "CSV" file is not CSV; it looks like either space- or tab-delimited.  read.csv2() assumes semi-colon-delimited by default.  Does the file really look like what you have pasted here?

Comment: @neilfws Sorry, copy-n-pasted from excel. Semi-colon separated CSV.

Comment: @klonq : You should remember to use `str(s_data)` or `names(s_data)` if you're not sure what s_data contains. You would've seen immediately that `Main status` is in fact `Main.status`.

Comment: After `s_data <- read.csv2( file=f_name )` you should add `str(s_data)` which show you how look your imported data.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Unless you specify `check.names=FALSE`, R will convert column names that are not valid variable names (e.g. contain spaces or special characters or start with numbers) into valid variable names, e.g. by replacing spaces with dots. Try `names(s_data)`.  If you **do** use `check.names=TRUE`, then use single back-quotes (`) to surround the names.

I would also recommend using `rename` from the `reshape` package (or, these days, `dplyr::rename`).

```
s_data <- read.csv2( file=f_name )
library(reshape)
s_df <- rename(s_data,ID="scada_id",
               PlantNo="plant",DateTime="date",Main.status="main_code",
               Additional.status="seco_code",MainStatustext="main_text",
               AddStatustext="seco_test",Duration="duration")
```

For what it's worth, the tidyverse tools (i.e. `readr::read_csv`) have the opposite default; they don't transform the column names to make them legal R symbols unless you explicitly request it.

Answer (score 16):

```
s_data <- read.csv( file=f_name , check.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe spaces get replaced by dots "." when importing CSV files.  So you'd write e.g. `Main.status`.  You can check by entering `names(s_data)` to see what the names are.