# rpy2 rmagic for ipython converting dashes to dots in dataframe column names

Tags: python, r, ipython, jupyter, rpy2

I am using rpy2 through the rmagic to interleave R code with python3 code in a jupyter notebook. A simple code cell as this:

```
%%R -i df -o df_out
df_out <- df
```

returns some column names changed, e.g. `CTB-102L5.4` becomes `CTB.102L5.4`. I think this is related with `read.table` or similar (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6124646/41977)). However I didn't find a way to specify this in the rmagic extension.

The only workaround I could think is to change the column names before passing them to R and reverting back them when the dataframe is back in python, but I'd like to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever using the parameter `-i <name>` to "import" a Python object into R, conversion rules are applied (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/5a9c102a47e4c20fb688f536a57e7be6a7d5330f/rpy/ipython/rmagic.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#rmagic.py-684)). The default converter is ending up calling R's function `data.frame`, which will sanitize the column names (parameter `check.names=TRUE` by default, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.3/topics/data.frame) to valid-yet-unquoted symbol names. In your example, `CTB-102L5.4` would otherwise be parsed as the expression `CTB - 102L5.4`.

This default behaviour is not necessarily desirable in every situation, and a custom converter can be passed to the R magic `%%R`.

The documentation contains a short introduction to writing custom conversion rules (https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_convert.html).

Assuming that your input is a `pandas` DataFrame, you could proceed as follows:

1- implement a variant of [py2ri_pandasdataframe](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/src/5a9c102a47e4c20fb688f536a57e7be6a7d5330f/rpy/robjects/pandas2ri.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#pandas2ri.py-52) that does not sanitize names. Ideally by just setting `check.names` to `FALSE`, although currently not possible because of https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/455/add-parameter-to-dataframe-to-allow).

```
def my_py2ri_pandasdataframe(obj):
    res = robjects.pandas2ro.py2ri_pandasdataframe(obj)
    # Set the column names in `res` to the original column names in `obj`
    # (left as an exercise for the reader)
    return res
```

2- create a custom converter derived from the ipython converter

```
import pandas
from rpy2.ipython import rmagic
from rpy2.robjects.conversion import Converter, localconverter

my_dataf_converter = Converter('my converter')
my_dataf_converter.py2ri.register(pandas.DataFrame,
                                  my_py2ri_pandasdataframe)

my_converter = rmagic.converter + my_dataf_converter
```

3- Use `%%R` with `--converter=my_converter`.